# Redirect all http and https://www to https://example.com via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# enable Rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

# redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

I am already did the redirect from `http://` to `https://`, but I would like to redirect also (for seo reasons), all URLs from `https://www` to `https`

but I have no idea how this can be done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

# http(s) www -> https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
# http -> https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```